# How to change component's state from another component

Tags: reactjs

I have two react components: `Question` and `lose`.
Here's `lose`'s state - `this.state = { display: none }`
I have a button in `Question` and i want to make function which will activate on click and change `lose`'s state. How can I do that?

Comment: A common technique for these situations is to [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the parent component instead and pass that state down as props to the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `lost` is the parent component, you should declare an event handler that controls the `display` property in state in `lost`.

for example in `lost` you write:

```
changeDisplayToBlock = () => {
  this.setState({display: 'block'})
}
```

You should pass this handler to the button in component `Question` as a prop. This means that `Question` has to be a child of `lost`.

If you meant it to be the other way around where `Question` is the parent. Then you'd need to have the `display` state and `changeDisplayToBlock` event handler in the component `Question`.

The concepts I'm using here are explained well in React docs [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) :)